# Microsoft Outlook Rule Changing Who Emails are Forwaded To

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook

I trying to find a way to automate something in Outlook. At my work, we have an on call email alert system. Right now I go into the MailStreet GUI and change who is in the distribution group every week.

Every week it changes to a different people in a cycle. There are two people on call every week with two groups. One group has four people in it, the other has five people in it.

Is there anyway to create an Outlook rule to automate this switching of who the on call email alerts go to?

EDIT: Answers to Comments

1. I want the emails to be sent immediately when received. Since these are "on-call" emails, they go to people regardless of time.
2. Multiple monitoring services are sending the emails, not just one. It may only be like fifteen, so not too bad.
3. And for the third question by @KCotreau, I don't know what you are asking... I am trying to figure out where to start with an Outlook rule since it is such a weird thing to want.

If you have any other questions, please let me know.

Comment: What is missing from the question is exactly what Outlook/Exchange is trying to do and what is happening. You want it to send a message on a schedule, or you want to forward a message when it receives one? Who is sending the message in the first place? So if you can edit the question to say something like, when this programs does this, this happens, but we want it to do this, it would be helpful.